# Error when installing pylibmc using pip and Python 3

Tags: python, pip, osx-elcapitan, pyenv, pylibmc

I have followed the steps and have

```
brew install libmemcached

echo /usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/
-> /usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/

pyenv versions
->
  system
  2.7.11
  3.3.6
  3.3.6/envs/p3venv
* p3venv (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)

pip install pylibmc --install-option="--with-libmemcached=/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/"
```

**Error:**

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DUSE_ZLIB -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/include -I/Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/envs/p3venv/include -I/Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/include/python3.3m -c src/_pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.3/src/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:2602:10: warning: 'sasl_client_init' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.11 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        rc = sasl_client_init(NULL);
             ^
    /usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:924:17: note: 'sasl_client_init' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    LIBSASL_API int sasl_client_init(const sasl_callback_t *callbacks) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0,__MAC_10_11,__IPHONE_NA,__IPHONE_NA);
                    ^
    src/_pylibmcmodule.c:2623:19: warning: 'sasl_done' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.11 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        if (Py_AtExit(sasl_done)) {
                      ^
    /usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:727:18: note: 'sasl_done' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    LIBSASL_API void sasl_done(void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0,__MAC_10_11,__IPHONE_NA,__IPHONE_NA);
                     ^
    2 warnings generated.
    clang -bundle -bundle_loader /Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/bin/python3.3 -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/lib build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.3/src/_pylibmcmodule.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/lib -lmemcached -lz -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.3/_pylibmc.so
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_sasl_client_init", referenced from:
          _PyInit__pylibmc in _pylibmcmodule.o
      "_sasl_done", referenced from:
          _PyInit__pylibmc in _pylibmcmodule.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/envs/p3venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/b7/fbjhqw1j11g565tzy671qyjh0000gn/T/pip-build-26vdrp/pylibmc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/b7/fbjhqw1j11g565tzy671qyjh0000gn/T/pip-6qsy4t-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/houman/.pyenv/versions/3.3.6/envs/p3venv/include/site/python3.3/pylibmc --with-libmemcached=/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_1/" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b7/fbjhqw1j11g565tzy671qyjh0000gn/T/pip-build-26vdrp/pylibmc/
```

Comment: Is your `sasl` library x86 and not x86_64?

Comment: Does `file` *path to `sasl` library* work?

Comment: That being said, it could be some other lib implementing `_sasl_client_init` and `_sasl_done`. That lib is likely not x86_64.